# Is the word "there" an adjective in this sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, parts-of-speech, fronting

CONTEXT:

> I can't find my ring.
>   Oh, there it is.

Is the word "there" an adjective in the sentence above? or is it a pronoun? For me it looks like the word "it" is the pronoun, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: No, locative "there" is not an adjective. For some people it's an adverb, for others a preposition. "It" is a pronoun serving as a proform which has "my ring" as antecedent. "There", by contrast, is deictic in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"There" is an adverb in your sentence - specifically a *locative adverb* or *[adverb of place](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-place/)*. Example sentences include:

> I need to go back to the office because I left my wallet **there**.
>
> I've heard Switzerland is lovely, but I've never been **there**.
>
> "Where is Bobby? **There** he is.

See the top definition [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there) for more details.

Also, you are correct that "it" is the pronoun in your sentence.

Comment: I thought of adverb, too, but the "there" in "there's my ring" and "my ring is there" are different.  I can agree that in "my ring is there" it's an adverb, but "there it is" doesn't have the same deep structure as "it is there", though at first blush you'd think it would.

Comment: @MMacD they are not different

Comment: It has the same deep structure; locatives can be displaced to the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

"It" is indeed the pronoun.  "There" in that construction is an exclamatory  preposition rather than an adjective, though I agree that it feels as though it has some "adjective flavor".

Comment: "There" **cannot** be a preposition.

Comment: Certainly not in traditional grammar, but in post-Jespersen grammar yes.

Comment: @D. Nelson Huddleston & Pullum in their CGEL call locative "there" an intransitive preposition.

Answer (score 0):

*There* has its ordinary use as a locative, equivalent to the preposition phrase *in/at that place*.

The canonical structure of the sentence is "It is there". Ordinarily when a constituent in the predicate is "fronted" to the beginning of the sentence the verb is kept in the second position and the subject moves after it; this puts the subject in the "new information" position, and it receives the primary emphasis:

> On the shelf were **two candles**.
>   Here comes **the train**.
>   There goes **John**.

But when the subject is a personal pronoun it is almost by definition "old information"—it has already been introduced into the discourse. The subject and verb remain in place.

> Here it comes.
>   There he goes.
>   There it is!

THe fronted constituent in this construction is almost always *here* or *there*. The construction is typically used to announce an expected or sought-for event. If the verb is *BE*, as in your example, the fronted constituent gets the primary emphasis, and the sentence announces that the expected event has finally occurred:

> **There** it is! = *I've found it (at last)* or *It's arrived (at last)*.

With other verbs the primary emphasis usually falls on the verb, and the sentence announces that the expected event is finally in progress:

> Here it **comes**. = *At last! It's coming!*
>   There he **goes**. = *He's departing, as we expected* or, figuratively *And now he's doing just what we expected*.